# How to get the values of a dictionary using key path

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have 2 dictionaries. 
Dict 1 : The values are the path of the key of the second dict.

I need to fetch the key and value from get Dict 1 and with the path get the value from Dict 2.

> dict2:

```
dict2 = { 
          "s0" : 
          {
             "s1"  :  {
                   "s1_f1":"s1_v1",
                   "s1_f2" : "s1_v2"
                 },
              "s2":   {
                   "s2_f1":"s2_v1",
                   "s2_f2" : "s2_v2",
                   "s2_f3" : {
                                "s3_f1":"s3_v1"
                             }
                 }
          }
}
```

> dict1:

```
dict1 = {
        "d0_f1":"s0/s1/s1_f1",
        "d3_f1" : "s0/s2/s2_f3/s3_f1",
        "d1_f1":"s0/s2/s2_f1",
        "d1_f2" :"s0/s2/s2_f2"
      }
```

> Output:

For each key and value from dict1 get the values of the keys in dict2
in dict 1 the value of

```
{"d0_f1" = "s1_v1"}
```

> Code:

```
def find_in_input_json(element, input_json):
    keys = element.split('/')
    rv = input_json
    for key in keys:
        rv = rv[key]
    return rv
value = find_in_input_json(key_value, input_json)
print(value)
```

This is giving an error message

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Comment: Is `key_value` a dictionary?

Comment: No, it is a list

Comment: Based on the error, it's 100% correct that element is not a `string` but just a `dict`.

Comment: @vartika, can you please mention or show that in problem description? I guess, it might be a `dict` containing `list`.

Comment: Well, Python says that it's a `dict`ionary, so you'd better double-check that.

Comment: @hygull it is a nested dictionary containing list within.

Comment: @vartika, okay, so `key_value` is indeed a dictionary. You're trying to call a `split('/')` method on this dictionary, but dictionaries do not have this method at all, so you get an error.

Comment: How to get the values of the dictionary using the key path

Comment: @vartika, I think you can just do `find_in_input_json("your/key/path", {"your": {"key": {"path": "yeah"}}})`

Comment: @vartika at least, please provide a little example similar to your `dict` and also mention what o/p you want. From the question, it is not clear, what o/p you want.

Comment: @hygull i have added the example

Comment: Okay, fine @vartika. Let me have a look. I have just answered with dummy example. Let me check your `dict` and I will update based on that.

Comment: I think, you can get little idea from this answer. Let me check your `dict`

Comment: @vartika, you can check my updated answer based on the input you provided. If you find any doubt, just let me know in comment. Thank you for the update. Good question. Made me busy to solve it.

Comment: i am still the same error paths = path.split('/') # ['s0', 's1', 's1_f1']
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: Try the code in my newly updated answer.

Comment: It works fine in my case, you can see in the commented part.

Answer (score 0):

#### `New answer` - `(Final updated)`

@vartika, thanks for updating the problem with desired i/p & o/p as it helped me to help you.

You can use below code to accomplish the task or solve this problem. I have commented out few lines just to make my points clear to you and I think code is clean and easy to understand.

You can comment if you find any difficulty.

```
def find_in_input_json(element, input_json):
    values = {} # Output dictionary with key in dict1: matched value

    for d_f in dict1:
        path = dict1[d_f]       # "s0/s1/s1_f1"
        paths = path.split('/') # ['s0', 's1', 's1_f1']
        rv = input_json

        for s in paths: # s: s0 -> s1 -> s1_f1 (one by one)
            if s in rv:
                rv = rv[s] # Update input_json with new dictionary pointed by current matched key

        values[d_f] = rv # {'d0_f1': 's1_v1'} ->  {'d0_f1': 's1_v1', 'd3_f1': 's3_v1'} -> so...on

    return values


if __name__ == '__main__':
    dict1 = {
        "d0_f1": "s0/s1/s1_f1",
        "d3_f1": "s0/s2/s2_f3/s3_f1",
        "d1_f1": "s0/s2/s2_f1",
        "d1_f2": "s0/s2/s2_f2"
    }

    dict2 = {
        "s0": {
            "s1": {
                "s1_f1": "s1_v1",
                "s1_f2": "s1_v2"
            },
            "s2": {
                "s2_f1": "s2_v1",
                "s2_f2": "s2_v2",
                "s2_f3": {
                    "s3_f1": "s3_v1"
                }
            }
        }
    }

    values = find_in_input_json(dict1, dict2)
    print(values) # {'d0_f1': 's1_v1', 'd3_f1': 's3_v1', 'd1_f1': 's2_v1', 'd1_f2': 's2_v2'}
```

#### `Old answer`

@vartika, as I understood from the problem & comments, you have a nested dictionary with any list in it.

So I just considered the following list.

Here I created 2 dictionaries, `key_value` & `input_json`.

Inside function, I am doing the below operations.

- Get the value of `element` key in `key_value` dictionary.
- `element`'s value is a string (`path`) `/` separated i.e. `'/Users/hygull/Desktop/Python3/file1/output'`, so using `split()` method is fine here as you have used in your code.
- Finally, I am iterating over the path elements and also checking if that path element is a key in `input_json`. If it is grab the corresponding value and break out of the loop.
- Return the value to caller.

Now you can have a look at the below code.

```
def find_in_input_json(element, input_json):
    # Fetch element keys value
    element = element['file']["element"] # '/Users/hygull/Desktop/Python3/file1/output'

    keys = element.split('/') 
    print(keys) # ['', 'Users', 'hygull', 'Desktop', 'Python3', 'file2', 'output']

    rv = input_json

    for key in keys:
        if key in rv:     # 'file2' key is in input_json
            rv = rv[key]  # Get its value
            break         # Exit from loop, don't go further 

    return rv             # Return the value


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # TEST CASE 1
    key_value = {
        'file': {
            'name': 'a.py',
            'element': '/Users/hygull/Desktop/Python3/file2/output',
            'children': [
                'b.py',
                'c.py'
            ]
        }
    }

    input_json = {
        'file1': {
            'name': 'a.py',
            'element': '/Users/hygull/Desktop/Python3/file2/output',
            'children': [
                'b.py',
                'c.py'
            ]
        },
        'file2': {
            'name': 'c.py',
            'element': '/Users/hygull/Desktop/Python3/file1/output',
            'children': [
                'd.py',
                'e.py'
            ]
        },
        'file3': {
            'name': 'x.py',
            'element': '/Users/hygull/Desktop/Python3/file4/output',
            'children': [
                'y.py',
                'z.py'
            ]
        }
    }

    value = find_in_input_json(key_value, input_json)
    print(value) # {'name': 'c.py', 'element': '/Users/hygull/Desktop/Python3/file1/output', 'children': ['d.py', 'e.py']}
```